# SublimeText Find in files Plugin

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, findinfiles

I have a source code base with a lot of re-directions (mostly #defines)
I want to write a plugin that find the definition, and then automatically find all "references".
I'm done with the "conversation", so from 10 I find SIZE_OF_HASHSTAG or etc, but can not start automatic(built in) find in files method.

I already tried:

```
where = 'my_src_dir'
args = { "panel": "find_in_files", "in_selection": "true", "where": where}
sublime.active_window().run_command("show_panel", args)
```

Ofc I could do it myself with a python script, but it would be easier if I could use the built-in.

Comment: what are asking excatly?

Comment: I want call find in files from a plugin, and i do not want to hit the ENTER or click on Find button, just get the same result. If it is possible w/o panel, it would be better.